# Plotting a $3$-dimensional convex shape consisting of portions of six spheres

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, geometry

How can we plot a convex shape $C$ in the $3$-dimensional Euclidean space, whose boundary $\partial C$ is formed by portions of six different spheres, one portion per sphere? The radius of each sphere is the same, $a+1$, and the coordinates of six spheres centers are $(a,0,0), (-a,0,0), (0,a,0), (0,-a,0), (0,0,a), (0,0,-a)$, where the parameter $a$ is a non negative real number. Hence, each sphere passes through one and only one of the following points for $a>0$:

$(1,0,0), (-1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,-1,0), (0,0,1), (0,0,-1)$.

Finally, for each of such points $\mathbf{p}$, the portion of the sphere $S_{\mathbf{p}}$ passing through it consists of all points of $S_{\mathbf{p}}$ whose distance from  $\mathbf{p}$ is smaller than the distance between $\mathbf{p}$ and any point of the other five spheres.

---

Note that for $a=0$, $C$ is the sphere with unit radius centered at the origin. As $a$ grows we have a shape always lying in $[-1,1]^3$, where the Gaussian curvature is the same at any point of $C$ is everywhere the same (and larger than the unit sphere as $a$ grows). For $a\to\infty$, we have the cube $[-1,1]^3$. Hence, this convex shape can be viewed as a continuous transformation from the unit sphere to its bounding box $[-1,1]^3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the new [`CSGRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CSGRegion.html) functionality, we can an extremely fast and accurate result:

```
Manipulate[
 CSGRegion["Intersection", 
  Ball[a #, a + 1] & /@ {{1, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, -1, 
     0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, -1}}],
 {a, 0, 5}
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A somewhat slow solution is using an ImplicitRegion:

```
Manipulate[
 sp = Ball[#, 1 + a] & /@ {{a, 0, 0}, {\[Minus]a, 0, 0}, {0, a, 
     0}, {0, \[Minus]a, 0}, {0, 0, a}, {0, 0, \[Minus]a}};
 Region[ImplicitRegion[
   And @@ ({x, y, z} \[Element] # & /@ sp), {x, y, z}]]
 , {{a, .5}, 0, 1}]
```

[image]